# .NET Core 3.0 RouteEndpoint - how to return RedirectToActionResult?

Tags: c#, httpcontext, asp.net-core-3.0, .net-core-3.0, asp.net-authorization

Using .NET Core 3.0 - it doesn't support AuthorizationFilterContext and I need to redirect a user to error page when authentication fails.

AuthHandlerCode:-

```
public class CheckADGroupHandler : AuthorizationHandler<CheckADGroupRequirement>
{
   private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

   public CheckADGroupHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
   {
      _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor ?? throw new 
      ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContextAccessor));
   }

   protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,CheckADGroupRequirement requirement)
   { 

    if (wi.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        context.Succeed(requirement);
    }
    else
    {
        var endPoint = (Endpoint)context.Resource;
        var attributes = endPoint.Metadata.GetOrderedMetadata<Attribute>();
        var action = endPoint.Metadata.GetMetadata<ControllerActionDescriptor>();

        //Redirect user to Error page here.....<<<<

        //below Code doesn't work in .NET Core 3.0
        //var mvcContext = context.Resource as AuthorizationFilterContext;
        //mvcContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/Shared/Error");
        //context.Succeed(requirement);

    }
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

I followed this [Link](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/12564) and [this one](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/15263) but neither doesn't show how to return redirect result in .NET Core 3.0

Any pointers appreciated....

Comment: That's impossible in `ASP.NET Core 3.0`. As a walkaround, I would suggest you should use a `ResourceFilter` in which you can invoke the `AuthorizationService` and then you can set the `context.Result=new RedirectResult(...)`

Comment: @itminus can't find an example of how to do that...

Comment: e.g.: implement the `IAsyncResourceFilter:: OnResourceExecutionAsync(ResourceExecutingContext context, ResourceExecutionDelegate next)` method: 
`var HttpContext = context.HttpContext;var authZ = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IAuthorizationService>();
var result = await authZ.AuthorizeAsync(HttpContext.User,  your-resource, your-policy);
if(!result.Succeeded){
    context.Result = new RedirectToActionResult(...);
   }await next();
}
`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to user redirect to some page like login page, if user didn't has access, you could following below steps for fix it:

1. into `HandleRequirementAsync`  method

   ```
       if (Condition())
       {
           context.Succeed(requirement);
       }
       else {
           context.Fail();
       }
   ```

if user did has access, execute   `context.Succeed(requirement);` and if user didn't has access, execute   `context.Fail();`

2. into `startup.cs` => `ConfigureServices` method

   ```
   services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
   {
       options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
       options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(12);
       options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
       options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
       options.SlidingExpiration = true;
   });
   ```

in line that we write

```
 options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
```

we appointment users after failing in `HandleRequirementAsync`  method for checking access, being redirected to controller 'home' controller  and 'login' actiion.

i'll hope my answer be useful.